# Magento 2.4 collection filtering no longer working - strange paging issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I'll start by saying that this worked correctly prior to Magento 2.4.
using $collection->addAttributeToFilter("sku",'21V12') does seem to filter the products, but it does so very strangely.  if i have 20 products in a category and i use that filter, there are 2 different scenarios

1. The results are correct and it shows 1 of 1
2. The results show "We can't find products matching the selection."
   the difference is that if the sku i'm filtering on is on page 1, then i get the first results, but if the sku is on a different page, i get the "We can't find products matching the selection."

If I add the page to the url, I get the result (adding p=2 or p=3 for example)

Any idea why that is? I've tried this in multiple points in the code to no avail.

That filtering on sku is a simple example, but lets say we want to do a more involved filter like

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter("special_name",'some_custom_text')
```

and that gives 20 results, sometimes there are none on page 1 and 3 on page 2, etc.

Anyway, it seems to just be hiding items in the display and not actually giving the results we are looking for.

I've tested this on a baseline 2.4.2 install with the Luma theme.

To verify, the easiest way, add this at line 147 in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter("sku",'21V12');
```

Substitute a sku you have on page 2 of a category page.  you should get the "We can't find products matching the selection." page, but if you add ?p=2 (or whatever page your item is on normally) you'll get that product as a result.

Comment: in case this helps anyone else.  there is a magento bug that is being worked on, but hasn't been resolved as of this post.       https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34292